# How to use groupby on a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, graph

I have a dataframe (survey) in which i need to groupby 2 columns.
One of the 2 columns is a ranking (5 options : Very Poor, Poor, Average, Good and Excellent) and the second one is a list of times.
I need to groupby both of those columns like that :

```
raking    |   Time   |  Count of how many times the time appears on the column "time" for a raking  
-------------------------------------
Very poor |  0.0     |   6
          |  1.0     |   2    
          |  2.0     |   9             
-------------------------------------                              
Poor      |  0.0     |   3                           
          |  1.0     |   12                          
...
```

I need to show the results of these table in 5 graphs (one for each raking), with x=Time and Y=Count

I've been stuck for a few hours now, can someone help???

Comment: Please provide a sample of your original dataframe using `df.to_dict()`

Comment: {'ID': {0: 'R1',
  1: 'R2',
  2: 'R3',
  3: 'R4'},
 
 'Region of residence': {0: 'Delhi-NCR',
  1: 'Delhi-NCR',
  2: 'Delhi-NCR',
  3: 'Delhi-NCR'},
 
'Age of Subject': {0: 21,
  1: 21,
  2: 20,
  3: 20},
 
 'Time spent on Online Class': {0: 2.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 7.0,
  3: 3.0},
 
 'Rating of Online Class experience': {0: 'Good',
  1: 'Excellent',
  2: 'Very poor',
  3: 'Very poor'},
 
  'Time spent on self study': {0: 4.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 3.0,
  3: 2.0},
}
 
 This is a sample, i need to groupby the rating of online classes with the time spent on self study

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```
rank = ['Very Poor', 'Poor', 'Average', 'Good', 'Excellent']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Ranking':  np.random.choice(rank, 100),
                   'Time': np.random.randint(1, 50, 100)})
print(df)

# Output:
      Ranking  Time
0   Excellent    28
1        Poor    33
2   Excellent    28
3     Average    22
4   Very Poor    11
..        ...   ...
95  Very Poor    13
96    Average    26
97  Very Poor    23
98       Good    24
99       Good    36

[100 rows x 2 columns]
```

Use [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) to count (Ranking, Time) rather than `groupby`:

```
count = df.value_counts(['Ranking', 'Time']).rename('Count').reset_index()
print(count)

# Output:
      Ranking  Time  Count
0        Poor    41      3
1   Very Poor    46      3
2   Very Poor    49      2
3   Very Poor    17      2
4   Excellent    20      2
..        ...   ...    ...
81  Excellent    34      1
82  Excellent    32      1
83  Excellent    27      1
84  Excellent    26      1
85       Good    32      1

[86 rows x 3 columns]
```

To visualize data, the easiest way is to use [`seaborn`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/) and [`displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html):

```
# Python env: pip install seaborn
# Anaconda env: conda install seaborn
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.displot(df, x='Time', col='Ranking', binwidth=1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much for your help !!

Comment: Done! Thanks again!!